# Checkbox está pegando apenas a primeira linha da tabela

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, estou estudando e estou tendo uma dificuldade com isso, tenho uma tabela com alguns dados que vem do banco Postgre, gerei um checkbox para pegar os dados da linha da tabela solicitada  para poder aceitar o trabalho, entretanto independente do linha do checkbox ele só pega os dados da primeira.

[image: retornando dados da primeira linha,]

Quando clico no checkbox da ultima linha ele não retorna os dados da linha correspondente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Oque posso estar fazendo de errado ?

```
var linha;
function deletar() {
    var myTD = document.getElementById('ordersTable').getElementsByTagName('tr')[linha];
    myTD.parentNode.removeChild(myTD);
}

function selecionar(name) {
    linha = document.forms["form"].elements[name].value;
    var status = document.forms["form"].elements[name].checked;
    popularInputs(linha, status);
}

function popularInputs(td, status) {
    if (status === false) {
        limpeza();
    } else {
        document.forms["form"].elements["nome"].value = document.getElementById("nome" + td).innerHTML;
        document.forms["form"].elements["trabalhos"].value = document.getElementById("trabalhos" + td).innerHTML;
        document.forms["form"].elements["celular"].value = document.getElementById("celular" + td).innerHTML;
        document.forms["form"].elements["email"].value = document.getElementById("email" + td).innerHTML;
    }
}

function limpeza() {
    document.forms["form"].elements["nome"].value = "";
    document.forms["form"].elements["trabalhos"].value = "";
    document.forms["form"].elements["email"].value = "";
    document.forms["form"].elements["celular"].value = "";
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="form"  method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table id="ordersTable" summary="Tabela de dados de uma agenda" class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="marcar" name="marcar" /></th>

                <th scope="col">Nome do Cliente </th>
                <th scope="col">Email do Cliente </th>
                <th scope="col">Telefone do Cliente </th>
                <th scope="col">Dia para contato </th>
                <th scope="col">Tipo de trabalhos </th>
                <th scope="col">Mensagem </th>

            </thead>
            {% for value in List %}
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="marcar0"
                            onclick="return selecionar(this.name);" /></td>
                    <td id="nome" class="dark-row" scope="row">{{value.nome}}</th>
                    <td id="email" class="light-row">{{value.email}}</td>
                    <td id="celular" class="light-row">{{value.celular}}</td>
                    <td class="light-row">{{value.data}}</td>
                    <td id="trabalhos" class="light-row">{{value.trabalhos}}</td>
                    <td class="light-row">{{value.mensagem}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <h2>Aceitar trabalho</h2>
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
        <input type="text" name="trabalhos" placeholder="Trabalho" />
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="tel" name="celular" placeholder="Telefone" />
        <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Aceitar" />
        <input type="submit" name="remover" value="Remover" onclick="return deletar();" />
    </form>
```

Obrigado desde ja pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema o checkbox estava pegando sempre o mesmo indice, utilizei a chave primaria da minha tabela como o ID em todas as linhas que necessitava do checkbox e alterei para radio para não ter problema.

JS

```
function popularInputs(td) {
    document.forms["form"].elements["nome"].value = document.getElementById("nome" + td).innerHTML;
    document.forms["form"].elements["trabalhos"].value = document.getElementById("trabalhos" + td).innerHTML;
    document.forms["form"].elements["celular"].value = document.getElementById("celular" + td).innerHTML;
    document.forms["form"].elements["email"].value = document.getElementById("email" + td).innerHTML;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <h2>Caixa de entrada</h2>
    <form name="form"  method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table id="ordersTable" summary="Tabela de dados de uma agenda" class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <th></th>
                
                <th scope="col">Nome do Cliente </th>
                <th scope="col">Email do Cliente </th>
                <th scope="col">Telefone do Cliente </th>
                <th scope="col">Dia para contato </th>
                <th scope="col">Tipo de trabalhos </th>
                <th scope="col">Mensagem </th>

            </thead>
            {% for value in List %}
            <tbody>
                <tr teste="{{id_cliente}}">
                    <td><input type="radio" id="{{value.id_cliente}}" name="a"
                            onclick="popularInputs(this.id)" /></td>
                    <td id="nome{{value.id_cliente}}" class="dark-row" scope="row">{{value.nome}}</th>
                    <td id="email{{value.id_cliente}}" class="light-row">{{value.email}}</td>
                    <td id="celular{{value.id_cliente}}" class="light-row">{{value.celular}}</td>
                    <td class="light-row">{{value.data}}</td>
                    <td id="trabalhos{{value.id_cliente}}" class="light-row">{{value.trabalhos}}</td>
                    <td class="light-row">{{value.mensagem}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <h2>Aceitar trabalho</h2>
        <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" />
        <input type="text" name="trabalhos" placeholder="Trabalho" />
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
        <input type="tel" name="celular" placeholder="Telefone" />
        <input type="submit" name="cadastrar" value="Aceitar" onclick="return alerta();"/>
        <input type="reset" value="Limpar"/>
        
    </form>
</div>
```

Espero que isso ajude alguem futuramente. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Lendo seu código na parte do HTML tem um javascript no evento click que é ai que você esta capturando os dados, só que você definiu que todos os input tem o mesmo name="marcar0" acredito que é isso que esta dando o erro e trazendo os dados onde não esta marcado, da pra fazer um debug ai nessa parte pra ver tenta assim:

```
<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name={{value.name}}
                        onclick="return selecionar(this.name);" /></td>
                <td id="nome" class="dark-row" scope="row">{{value.nome}}</th>
                <td id="email" class="light-row">{{value.email}}</td>
                <td id="celular" class="light-row">{{value.celular}}</td>
                <td class="light-row">{{value.data}}</td>
                <td id="trabalhos" class="light-row">{{value.trabalhos}}</td>
                <td class="light-row">{{value.mensagem}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentario, se coloco desse jeito ele nao pega nenhuma linha...

A parte do name="marcar0", ele é de um outro codigo que ela faz as linhas manualmente e coloca id em cada uma delas,  ai funciona, no meu caso as linhas  aparecem conforme a quantidade de dados que tem no banco... e não sei se da para colocar ID se for desse jeito, ja tentei colocar uma variavel {{value.id_cliente}}que tem no meu banco pra tentar simular mas também não consegui.